# How to convert string array to object using GSON/ JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, gson

I have a json like this:

```
[
  [
    "Passport Number",
    "NATIONALITY",
    "REASONS"
  ],
  [
    "SHAIS100",
    "INDIA",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "",
    "",
    "Agent ID is not matched."
  ],
  [
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ]
]
```

I want to populate this to `ArrayList<String[]>`,Please tell me how to do?

And empty strings should not convert as null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55691694/470749 was helpful for me. `list.add(item.getAsString());`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That's very simple, you just need to do the following:

1.- First create the `Gson` object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

2.- Then get the correspondent `Type` for your `List<String[]>` (Note that you can't do something like `List<String[]>.class` due to Java's [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)):

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String[]>>() {}.getType();
```

3.- Finally parse the JSON into a structure of type `type`:

```
List<String[]> yourList = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, type);
```

Comment: Type type = new TypeToken<List<String[]>>() {}.getType(); it should be 
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
similarly
List<String[]> yourList = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, type);  it should be 
List<String> yourList = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, type);

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at [Gson docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples_)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
String[] strings = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};

(Serialization)
gson.toJson(ints);     ==> prints [1,2,3,4,5]
gson.toJson(strings);  ==> prints ["abc", "def", "ghi"]

(Deserialization)
int[] ints2 = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4,5]", int[].class); 
==> ints2 will be same as ints
```

Tis is important for you: *We also support multi-dimensional arrays, with arbitrarily complex element types*

For `null` objects, `Gson` by default will not convert as null. [Ref.](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support)
But you can configure to scan those `nulls` attributes if you want to do it after.

The default behaviour that is implemented in `Gson` is that null object fields are ignored.  This allows for a more compact output format; however, the client must define a default value for these fields as the `JSON` format is converted back into its Java.

*Here's how you would configure a `Gson` instance to output null:*

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

In your problem maybe you don't need to configure that.

I hope it helps.