# How to deserialize a key-value map to a list

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson

I want to work with crypto-stock data described [here](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/documentation?key=Price&cat=multipleSymbolsPriceEndpoint) in my spring boot application. The RESTTemplate uses Gson for deserialization. Response data looks like:

```
{
  "IOST": {
    "EUR": 0.01147,
    "USD": 0.01296
  },
  "XRP": {
    "EUR": 0.2837,
    "USD": 0.3208
  },
  ...
}
```

I have already already written a custom deserializer before. The problem is, that this comes as a single object with key-value pairs insted of as an array. The result should be a list of following objects:

```
public class Symbol {
    private Long id; // not relevant during conversion
    private Date timestamp; // not relevant during conversion
    private String symbol;
    private Double eurPrice;
    private Double usdPrice;
}
```

Any idea how this can be accomplished this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hareshs anweser didn't fit 100% but it helped me figuring it out:

```
var url = "...";
var entries = new ArrayList<Symbol>();
var timestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
Symbol symbol;

ResponseEntity<JsonObject> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, JsonObject.class);

for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : response.getBody().entrySet()) {
    symbol = new Symbol();
    symbol.setSymbol(entry.getKey());
    symbol.setEurPrice(entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("EUR").getAsDouble());
    symbol.setUsdPrice(entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("USD").getAsDouble());
    symbol.setTimestamp(timestamp);

    entries.add(symbol);
}
```

This does the trick. However, if anybody finds a way to do this completely within a Gson deserializer I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Because response from this `API` is dynamic and depends from parameters the best choice is to use dynamic structure on deserialisation side. The best choice is `Map`. As keys you can use `String` or `enum`: `Currency`, `Crypto`. After deserialisation you can convert `Map` to required `POJO` class. Simple example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"IOST\": {"
            + "    \"EUR\": 0.01147,"
            + "    \"USD\": 0.01296"
            + "  },"
            + "  \"XRP\": {"
            + "    \"EUR\": 0.2837,"
            + "    \"USD\": 0.3208"
            + "}}";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<Currency, BigDecimal>>>() {
        }.getType();

        Map<String, Map<Currency, BigDecimal>> response = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        List<Symbol> symbols = response.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> {
                Symbol symbol = new Symbol();
                symbol.setSymbol(e.getKey());
                symbol.setEurPrice(
                    e.getValue().getOrDefault(Currency.EUR, BigDecimal.ZERO).doubleValue());
                symbol.setUsdPrice(
                    e.getValue().getOrDefault(Currency.USD, BigDecimal.ZERO).doubleValue());

                return symbol;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(symbols);
    }

    enum Currency {
        EUR,
        USD
    }
}
```

Above example prints:

```
[Symbol{id=null, timestamp=null, symbol='IOST', eurPrice=0.01147, usdPrice=0.01296}, Symbol{id=null, timestamp=null, symbol='XRP', eurPrice=0.2837, usdPrice=0.3208}]
```

If you want to create directly `List` of `Symbol`-s you need to implement custom deserialiser. For example, take a look on this question: [Parsing JSON Array to Java List Using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688208/parsing-json-array-to-java-list-using-gson)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a class as below

```
public class Symbol  {

    private double EUR;
    private double USD;

    public double getEUR() {
        return EUR;
    }

    public void setEUR(double EUR) {
        this.EUR = EUR;
    }

    public double getUSD() {
        return USD;
    }

    public void setUSD(double USD) {
        this.USD = USD;
    }
}
```

Above is a model and  below is parsing

```
try {
        HashMap<String, Symbol> multiMap = new HashMap<String, Symbol>();
        JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(mResponse);
        Iterator<String> iter = mJsonObject.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            try {
                Symbol msymbol = new Symbol();
                msymbol.setEUR(mJsonObject.getJSONObject(key).getDouble("EUR"));
                msymbol.setEUR(mJsonObject.getJSONObject(key).getDouble("USD"));
                multiMap.put(key, msymbol);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Something went wrong!
            }
        }



    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Also, you can install a Gson Format plugin in your Android Studio and make Model Class. it is easy to use

Comment: This won't work. The response is a map, so `IOST` and `XRP` are just examples of keys provided by the OP.

Comment: Converting it into one, big object would work, but that's not exactly what I want. XRP and IOST are just two example values. There are plenty of them and which ones are used shouldn't be hard-coded.

Comment: then please provide you actual response

Comment: That should be able to differ. Here a full response: `{"IOST":{"EUR":0.01147,"USD":0.01296},"XRP":{"EUR":0.2837,"USD":0.3208},"LTC":{"EUR":70.28,"USD":79.43},"BCH":{"EUR":280.85,"USD":318.41},"EOS":{"EUR":4.78,"USD":5.42},"XLM":{"EUR":0.1001,"USD":0.1148},"ADA":{"EUR":0.0727,"USD":0.08201},"TRX":{"EUR":0.02333,"USD":0.02648},"XMR":{"EUR":57.61,"USD":64.94},"NEO":{"EUR":9.54,"USD":10.82},"VET":{"EUR":0.006085,"USD":0.006877},"RVN":{"EUR":0.05091,"USD":0.05752},"WAN":{"EUR":0.3643,"USD":0.4116},"WABI":{"EUR":0.4313,"USD":0.4872},"BTT":{"EUR":0.0006747,"USD":0.0007622}}`

Comment: I have updated my Answer  check, you can do it using this if working then accept my answer

Comment: @Madhu Bhat, I think this is working fine also i have checked