# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY" using Gson in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm trying to retrieve data from an api. The JSON response looks like this

```
{
    "result":"success",
    "documentation":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs",
    "terms_of_use":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms"
    "supported_codes":[
        ["AED","UAE Dirham"],
        ["AFN","Afghan Afghani"],
        ["ALL","Albanian Lek"],
        ["AMD","Armenian Dram"],
        ["ANG","Netherlands Antillian Guilder"],
        ["AOA","Angolan Kwanza"],
        ["ARS","Argentine Peso"],
        ["AUD","Australian Dollar"],
        ["AWG","Aruban Florin"],
        ["AZN","Azerbaijani Manat"],
        ["BAM","Bosnia and Herzegovina Convertible Mark"],
        ["BBD","Barbados Dollar"] etc. etc.
    ]
}
```

And this is the dataclass I have for it.

CurrencyResponse.kt

```
package com.example.currencyconverter.data

import com.squareup.moshi.Json

data class CurrencyResponse(
    @Json(name="supported_codes") var supported_codes: List<Codes>
) {
    data class Codes(
        @Json(name="0") var currency_code: String
    ) {

    }

}
```

Yet I'm still getting the error mentioned in the title. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Gson, but it doesn't seem right that you deserialize array (e.g. `["AED","UAE Dirham"]`) to `Codes` object. You probably need something like this: `var supported_codes: List<List<String>>` or maybe use a custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I think the API response scheme need a little modification. I think the `supported_codes` should contains list of object instead, i.e.

```
    "supported_codes":[
        {
             "currency_code": "AED",
             "currency_name": "UAE Dirham"
        },
        {
             "currency_code": "AFN",
             "currency_name": "Afghan Afghani"
        },
        ... etc ...
    ]
```

Then, in your kotlin code, you need to modify the `Codes` data class to:

```
data class Codes(
   @Json(name="currency_code") val currencyCode: String,
   @Json(name="currency_name") val currencyName: String,
)
```

Comment: But here's the thing, the array entries don't have a name so can I write "currency_code" and "currency_name" as names?

Comment: Unfortunately, it requires to change the API response schema as well. But, in my opinion, putting array of object inside `supported_codes` can help to ease the client side to identify the property passed, instead array of array

Comment: I changed it to this 
`
data class CurrencyResponse(
    @Json(name ="supported_codes") val supportedCodes: List<List<String>>
){

}

`

The app no longer crashes but I'm getting a null response

Comment: Or, you can try to parse `supportedCodes` as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974337