# How to describe JSON list with data classes in Kotlin / gson

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I want to parse the JSON from nominatim from OpenStreetMap.

[Example](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Tower%20Bridge&format=json)

It's a list and I don't have a clue how I can describe the list. I am using Gson, these is my data class:

```
data class Destination(
    val lat: Double,
    val lon: Double,
    val display_name: String
)
```

and this is my Gson implementation:

```
val list = Gson().fromJson<List<Destination>>(
    body,
    Destination::class.java
)
```

It gives me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

But I declared an Array in my Gson implementation. Anyone having an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you have to use an `Array`, not a `List`:

```
val list : Array<Destination> = Gson().fromJson(
    body,
    Array<Destination>::class.java
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize it as follow:

```
val type = object : TypeToken<List<Destination>>() {}.type
Gson().fromJson<List<Destination>>(body, type)
```

Similar to what was mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970128/how-to-convert-string-array-to-object-using-gson-json) question